# Call to PDO::exec() in destructor hangs PHP process

Tags: php, pdo, destructor

In the destructor of my test environment class I want do drop the test database. Executing this code in a ordinary method works fine.

Putting it into the destructor (or using `register_shutdown_function`) works as well but it causes my php process to never finish. Investigating the code with xdebug reveils, that `echo 'finished';` is never reached.

Any ideas why this causes the php process to hang?

```
public function __destruct()
{
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
    if ($config['dbtests']['autogenerate'] && $config['dbtests']['cleanup'] ) {
        /** @var \PDO $dbh  */
        $dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['database']['host'], $config['database']['user'], $config['database']['password']);
        $dbh->exec('DROP DATABASE ' . $config['database']['dbname']);
        echo 'finished';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, this code is from my test environment class. This is used to test doctrine entities.

I found that I have to mannualy close the db connection of the doctrine `EntityManager` before opening an other connection to this db. This is likely because I'm deleting the db which the connection of the `EntitiyManager` is pointing to.

The problem is not realted to `__destruct` or `register_shutdown_function`. I've been able to reproduce and finally fix the problem with ordinary user code.